Linux driver major number appears different across dmesg and gdb
PROBLEM:
I have a debug kernel running in QEMU/KVM with GDB attached. I am attempting to debug the ioctl calls of an LKM I am developing. My LKM registers a character device with a major number. I am noticing that the major number printed by GDB and ones reported in dmesg / procfs / sysfs are different.
LKM CODE:
I am storing the major number statically:
static char lainmemu_major;

My driver is acquiring a dynamic major number with:
lainmemu_major = (char) register_chrdev(0, MEMU_DEVICE_NAME, &file_ops);

The major number is then printed to dmesg with:
printk(KERN_INFO 
  "[lainmemu][OK] registered with major device number %d.\n", (unsigned char) lainmemu_major);


I have a sysfs attribute that stores the major number. The show() function for it is here:
static ssize_t lainmemu_major_show(const struct class * class, 
                                   const struct class_attribute * attr, char * buf) {

    return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", (unsigned char) lainmemu_major);
}

DMESG / PROCFS / SYSFS / GDB OUTPUT:
dmesg:
[lainmemu][OK] registered with major device number 246.

/proc/devices:
[...]
246 lainmemu
[...]

sysfs attribute:
# cat /sys/class/lainko/lainmemu_major
246
# hex 246
0xf6
# xxd /sys/class/lainko/lainmemu_major
00000000: 3234 360a      246.

However, when viewed with GDB:
(gdb) p lainmemu_major
$1 = 243 '\363'
(gdb) p/x lainmemu_major
$2 = 0xf3

QUESTION:
As you can see the difference is only 3. I'm looking for ideas as to what could be causing this. I am confident the VM and my host GDB are running/looking at the exact same kernel and module.
I have tried restarting the VM, my host machine, recompiling the LKM. Problem always persists.
The fact that procfs reports '246' makes me think its not a formatting problem caused by printf().
I am running Linux v6.10 using the default Debian config with various debug options enabled. Thanks for your time.
EDIT:
This appears to be a problem with GDB, although I have no idea what is causing it:
(gdb) p/x &lainmemu_major
$1 = 0xffffffffc0a89740
(gdb) p/x *0xffffffffc0a89740
$2 = 0xf6
(gdb) p/x lainmemu_major
$3 = 0xf3

QEMU invocation:
# kaslr disabled in GRUB config
exec qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S\
    -enable-kvm \
    -cpu host \
    -drive file=debug_image.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
    -m 2G \
    -monitor stdio \
    -name "debug_vm" \
    -virtfs local,path=/home/vykt/projects/kernel/debug_vm/shared,mount_tag=hostshare,security_model=mapped-xattr \
    "$@"

GDB invocation:
add-auto-load-safe-path /home/vykt/projects/kernel/linux-source-6.10/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
file ./vmlinux
target remote :1234
cont
[after kernel is running]
lx-symbols

LKM Makefile:
obj-m += lainko.o

all:
    make -C /home/vykt/linux-source-6.10/ M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /home/vykt/linux-source-6.10/ M=$(PWD) clean

EDIT 2:
All global variables have incorrect addresses. Only function addresses are resolved correctly by GDB. /proc/kallsyms and GDB do not match. I'm not sure why I thought they were the same when I checked this the first time.
While this problem looks much easier to fix, I am not sure why I got the GDB output that I did in my previous attempt.

It would be helpful for you to edit your question and (as applicable) post invocation commands for qemu, gdb, gdbserver, kvm. As well as any special config. Also, a bit more of your device driver source and maybe its Makefile. Link maps as needed (i.e. Does p/x &lainmenu_major address match the address from readelf/objdump and/or /proc/kallsyms?)

You might be able to run qemu under strace to see the raw data being transferred by gdb/gdbserver

Craig Estey: I've added QEMU, GDB invocations, and Makefile to the question. /proc/kallsyms has the exact same address as one reported by GDB. readelf --symbols lainko.ko shows a 0x40 offset into section, which seems correct.

It seems that GDB most likely messed up the kernel gloval variables with the module's one when accessing to it directly. I.o.w. how GDB is supposed to access global module variable if it doesn't (fully) know about memory layouts?

@0andriy the kernel GDB scripts (scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py) tell GDB about modules and their variables with lx-symbols: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.10/source/scripts/gdb/linux/symbols.py#L57

@MarcoBonelli, maybe, but see the Edit2 by OP, seems I have the correct theory.

Perhaps lx-symbols found a different version of the module.
